# How to change the table row color based on 3 conditions in React

Tags: reactjs, tablerow

Im new to react. I want to change the table row based on some conditions. Like I've a value called deadLine. So , if the difference between the deadLine date & current date is 2 then table row should be green , if the difference is 1 then table row should be yellow and if 0 or -ve then table row should be red.

Note: deadLine is a string which is in a format dd/MM/yyyy

How can i achieve this in react? I've seen some examples in stackOverflow but didnt help.

I've a code like this

```
<TableBody>
                {
                this.props.result.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map((row,i) =>(


                  <TableRow  key={i} >

                    <TableCell component="th"   >
                     <Typography variant="h4"> {row.a} </Typography>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left" > <Typography variant="h4">{row.b}</Typography>  </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left" > <Typography variant="h4"> {row.c} </Typography> </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left" > <Typography variant="h4"> {row.d} </Typography> </TableCell>
                    <TableCell align="left" > <Typography variant="h4"> {row.deadline} </Typography> </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>


                ))}
</TableBody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, define your CSS for styling

```
.green {} // green style
.yellow {} // yellow style
.red{} // red style
```

Then define your logical method to your component

```
.....
dateDiff = (deadLine) => {
  return (Date.parse(deadLine) - Date.now()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}
rowColor = (deadline) => {
   if (this.dateDiff(deadline) >= 2) {
      return 'green';
   } else if (this.dateDiff(deadline) >= 1) {
      return 'yellow';
   } else {
      return 'red';
   }
}
.....
render(){
 ......
 <TableBody>
{
this.props.result.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map((row,i) =>(


<TableRow className={this.rowColor(row.deadline)}  key={i} >

  <TableCell component="th"   >
    <Typography variant="h4"> {row.a} </Typography>
  </TableCell>
  <TableCell align="left" > <Typography variant="h4">{row.b}</Typography>  </TableCell>
  <TableCell align="left" > <Typography variant="h4"> {row.c} </Typography> </TableCell>
  <TableCell align="left" > <Typography variant="h4"> {row.d} </Typography> </TableCell>
  <TableCell align="left" > <Typography variant="h4"> {row.deadline} </Typography> </TableCell>
</TableRow>


))}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can just apply a class or a style property on `TableRow`:

`<TableRow style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>` will change the background of your row.

Better do it with classes so define your three classes in your css file :

```
.green{background-color: green;}
.yellow{background-color: yellow;}
.red{background-color: red;}
```

And then you can create a function that will return the class you need to apply, depending on deadline. Something like :

```
const getBackgroundColor = deadline => {
    return conditionToRed ? 'red' : conditionToYellow ? 'yellow' : 'green';
}
```

And in your jsx you will do something like :

```
<TableRow className={getBackgroundColor()}>
```